# Maximum number of Git remote URLs

Tags: git

Is there a limit -- practical or otherwise -- to the number of git remote URLs one can have in a single git repository?

For example, consider having 10,000 push-urls on a given remote.  Is it just a matter of time for something like `git push` to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remotes are usually tracked in `.git/config`. I made a test by running `n=0;while true;do n=$((n+1));git remote add $n http://$n;done` in a git repository for a while. It created 353,804 remotes before I pressed Ctrl-C. The size of `.git/config` is only 100K(As @OzgurMurat points out, the size is not right. It should be about 30M). I think the number depends on the maximum size of a single file that is allowed in the system.

As for the push I make another rather simple test. Because it takes significantly more time to initialize a git repository than to add a remote, I just initialized 10,000 local repositories that worked as remote repositories. Besides, I initialized another repository that worked as the local repository with 10,000 remotes. Via `echo hello world > aaa.txt;git add .;git commit -m'hello world'` I made a commit. `git push` can not work because there is no remote named `origin`. So I made a loop to do the push. `r=0;while [ $r -lt 10001 ];do r=$((r+1));git push $r master`;done`. It took quite some time to finish the pushes.

This test is not precise. After all a loop of pushes one by one is different from one push to all remotes which I have no idea how to accomplish. Besides, this test used the file protocol. In fact the git, ssh, or http protocols are more frequently used. They are different from and more complicated than the file protocol. But I think it is most likely a matter of time. In most real cases we are not likely to have more than 3 remotes in a repository.

Comment: Aside from the main point, just my curiosity: How did 353,804 remotes fit in 100K? 0.3 bytes per remote? :)

Comment: @OzgurMurat Thanks for pointing out this mistake. I had a check and found out I calculated some other number as the size. And I tried to reproduce the config but it was much slower. The config with 10,000 remotes is 877K, so it should be much bigger than 100K if the config had 353804 remotes.